# download in iPhone

Tags: iphone

When i will touch download link in any web page

is iphone downloads that content ?

if yes then where it will download ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't... unless and otherwise it's web content (which can be open by safari web browser...)

Comment: So if i see one online movie in iPhone.
and i want faciliate to download it in my iPhone...
is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari does not support downloading files other than files that are used on a web page.

Comment: So if i see one online movie in iPhone. and i want faciliate to download it in iPhone... is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The iphone can't download stuff. When you try to you'll see this error screen[image]